# How to pass parameter value for ExecuteReader() - powershell

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I am trying to run following powershell script. How Can I pass parameter value for @P0= '2019-11-22' and @P1 = '123456789' during runtime?

```
$sqlconnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$sqlconnection.ConnectionString = "server = Servername;Database=TestDB;Integrated security=true"
$sqlconnection.OPEN()

$sqlCmnd = New-OBJECT SYSTEM.DATA.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$sqlCmnd.Connection = $sqlconnection
$sqlCmnd.CommandText = "select distinct table1.column1, ..........  where table2.column='value' and table2.coulumn=@P0 and table2.column=@P1 order by table1.Column1"


$sqlCmnd.Parameters.ADD((New-OBJECT DATA.SQLClient.SQLParameter("@P0",[Data.SQLDBType]::varchar, 8000))) | OUT-NULL
$sqlCmnd.Parameters.ADD((New-OBJECT DATA.SQLClient.SQLParameter("@P1",[Data.SQLDBType]::varchar, 8000))) | OUT-NULL

$sqlCmnd.ExecuteReader()
$sqlconnection.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use PowerShell variables or script parameters to update in your script:

```
$P0 = "Value 0"
$P1 = "Value 1"

$sqlCmnd.Parameters.ADD((New-OBJECT DATA.SQLClient.SQLParameter("P0",[Data.SQLDBType]::varchar, 8000))).Value = $P0
$sqlCmnd.Parameters.ADD((New-OBJECT DATA.SQLClient.SQLParameter("P1",[Data.SQLDBType]::varchar, 8000))).Value = $P1
```

Comment: Thanks.  How do I pass different value instead of hard coding it? I am planning to run this script multiple times with different value.

Comment: You can assign a value to a script parameter or a variable, I updated the answer.